# There is a way to block system's user input using GTK in windows,linux?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I need to implement a desktop application that shows a window and block the user's input such as Alt+F4, Ctrl+Alt+Del, etc. until the application is running. There is a way that I can capture these events on Gtk and prevent it from propagating?

Comment: This is a question about Windows/X11. GTK has no such functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way -- these are basic OS functions that - quite rightly - the OS should not allow you to block. Imagine your application hanging and at the same time preventing the end-user from escaping this by instigating a forced quit? If your application is taking time to launch then I suggest using a Splash screen with some kind of loading progress indicator so the user knows what's going on.